# Why the value of j is 11?

Tags: c++, pointers

My code using C++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i = 10, j = 20, k;
    int* p = &i;
    int* q = &j;
    *p += 1;    
    p = &k;    
    *p = *q;    
    p = q;    
    *p = i;

    cout << j << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Please explain for me why `j` = 11? I tend it is a different value, but it is 11.

Comment: It would be a good learning exercise for you to either step through with a debugger and see what happens or to do it by hand and make sure you get 11.

Comment: To clarify your level of understanding, please add a comment to each line to explain what by your understanding the line does. Otherwise your questin is basically asking for a tutorial on pointers, which is off-topic for being to broad. (Downvote not by me.)

Comment: This also is a typical example of "Explain this code." homework assignments. Please consider asking for help according to the compromise described here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions Note that anything which gives the strong impression of being a blind homework assignment dump is also considered too broad a question.

Comment: Consider these helpful sources of information how this community is meant to be used: [tour], [ask], https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/ , https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: Somebody found that this post demonstrates own research effort, is useful and clear. Weird.

Comment: @Yunnosch - possibly the student's teacher gathering information they can use to decide what marks to award :-)

Comment: What "different value"? And why?

Comment: @Peter You mean a teacher has given that assignment and now wants some examples of (more or less) knowledgable answers? In most cases teachers have an ideo of what knowledge they actually want to probe... I think I don't get your point.

Comment: @Yunnosch Silly upvotes for _empathy_ not content I'd suspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope you can understand this, you need to know, when pointer point to a memory, and we call *pointer = valueX => memory will be set to valueX.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i = 10, j = 20, k;
    int* p = &i; // p point to i =>*p=10
    int* q = &j; // q point to j =>*q=20
    *p += 1; // *p = *p + 1 => *p=11 => i = 11   
    p = &k; // p point to k   
    *p = *q; // *p = 20 => k = 20   
    p = q; // p point to j (q point to j)   
    *p = i; // set value of memory which p point to to value of i => *p = 11 => j = 11

    cout << j << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After `// p point to k` the comment `// *p = 20 => i = 20` should be `// *p = 20 => k = 20`

Comment: yes, i was wrong at that place, i have updated. thanks

Comment: After see the anwer, I think `p` point to `q`, `q` point to `j`, value of `p` = 11, therefore j = 11. pointer `*p` and `*q` points to the same position.

Comment: @Asker Actually, there are only 3 lines that are pertinent == `int* p = &i; *p += 1; *p = i;` .  Every other line is just noise to confuse you.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I think it is not correct :), how do you know the value of j with your comment?